# Using enums in a spring boot thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am a beginner backend developer. I am building an application using Spring, Hibernate and of course Thymeleaf for the views.. I got such a problem. I want to send data from edit.html to another class. Here is my pages. Help me please.

edit.html (here is the problem).I want to put an enum in the PhoneList object and send it to the controller

```html
<div class="form-group"  th:each="phoneType, itemStat : ${form.phoneTypeList}">
    <select name="type">
        <option th:each="typeOpt : ${T(ru.murik.phone_book3.models.Type).values()}"
            th:value="${typeOpt}"
            th:text="${typeOpt}"
            th:selected="${phoneType.getType()} == ${typeOpt.toString()}"
            th:field="*{phoneType[__${itemStat.index}__].type}" >
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
```

PhoneList

```java
public class PhoneList {
    private List<Phone> phones;
    private List<PhoneType> phoneTypeList;

    public PhoneList(List<Phone> phones, List<PhoneType> phoneTypeList) {
        this.phones = phones;
        this.phoneTypeList = phoneTypeList;
    }

    public PhoneList() {
    }

    public List<Phone> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }

    public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
    }

    public List<PhoneType> getPhoneTypeList() {
        return phoneTypeList;
    }

    public void setPhoneTypeList(List<PhoneType> phoneTypeList) {
        this.phoneTypeList = phoneTypeList;
    }
}
```

controller

```java
@GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable("id")long id) {
    Contact contact = contactService.get(id);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("edit.html");
    List<PhoneType>typeList = new ArrayList<>();
    contact.getPhones().forEach(phone -> typeList.add(phone.getPhoneType()));
    PhoneList phoneList = new PhoneList(contact.getPhones(), typeList);


    modelAndView.addObject("contact", contact);
    modelAndView.addObject("form", phoneList);
    return modelAndView;
}

@PostMapping("/{id}")
public ModelAndView update(@PathVariable("id")long id,
                           @ModelAttribute("contact")Contact contact,
                           @ModelAttribute("phoneList")PhoneList phoneList){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/contact");

    for (PhoneType phoneType : phoneList.getPhoneTypeList()) {
        System.out.println(phoneType.getType());
    }

    Contact contact1 = contactService.get(id);

    for (int i = 0; i < phoneList.getPhones().size(); i++) {
        contact1.getPhones().get(i)
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneList.getPhones().get(i).getPhoneNumber());
    }

    contact1.setName(contact.getName());
    contact1.setSurname(contact.getSurname());


    contactService.save(contact1);
    return modelAndView;
}
```